# Загружается перевернутое изображение C#

Tags: c#

Изображение было снято на камеру, далее было перевернуто. При загрузке в PictureBox изображение отображается не перевернутым (то есть точно так же, как было снято). Как отследить, перевернуто изображение или нет? В Java для этого используется Exif, а как сделать подобное в C#?

Comment: Тоже можно из EXIF извлечь инфу, код можно взять из принятого ответа английского stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068941/images-are-rotated-in-picturebox

Comment: Вы наверное просто по настоящему не перевернули изображение. Скачайте paint.net, откройте файл в нем, переверните и сохраните как другой файл. Должно сработать!

Comment: @MichaelVaysman вопрос с поворотом должен разрешаться в рамках программы, иначе не комильфо заставлять пользователей проделывать действия, которые вы описали

Comment: @demonplus спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: @mtrfnv - тогда да. Просто в вопросе не совсем понятно в чем проблема - то что картинка не перевернута или то, как понять програмным способом перевернута картинка или нет :)

Comment: @MichaelVaysman вопрос заключался в определении, перевернута картинка или нет, программным способом